# AES decrypt with encrypt hardware

Tags: encryption, aes, hardware

I am using Nordic Nrf51822 chip, it has AES encrypt hardware support, but no decrypt hardware support, so I come up with following method
sender  -> XOR(data, AES(XOR(salt, counter = 1)) -> receiver
receiver is able to XOR back the data.
is there a better way, i.e. if AES is symmetric, we can do two encryption to get the original data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is similar to the standard [Counter (CTR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29) mode of operation. Indeed, with the hardware you have, any [mode of operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) that requires only the AES encrypt function can be used, e.g. [Cipher Feedback (CFB)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Feedback_.28CFB.29) and [Output Feedback (OFB)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Output_Feedback_.28OFB.29).

I would suggest you use one of the standard modes as described above, rather than rolling your own, which is generally ill-advised when it comes to cryptography.